# Label height increasing with white-spaces in value

Tags: label, vaadin

We're using Vaadin 6.8.9 in our project. We're creating popup window with vertical layout, add a couple of labels and button to it.

Strange thing is, when a label's value contains white-spaces (space, hyphen, etc.) it increases it's height by adding empty space below the text. For every space it looks like one empty line at the end is added. For hyphen it is less - half of line maybe. So to speak `a a a a a a a a` message takes a lot of empty space on screen (and the more labels, the worse).

There is no magic with window creation. We just create new windows and set it's width to 600 pixels. We do not set any other attributes for window, nor for labels. I couldn't reproduce it on fresh test Vaadin project, so I guess issues has to be with our app, yet I can't pinpoint it.

Here's the example code generated for one such label:

```html
<div style="height: 180px; width: 54px; overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px;">
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px;">
        <div class="v-label" style="width: 108px;">
            a a a a a a a a a a
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why first DIV is 180px high if label value is only one line? Where height calculation mechanism is located and is it possible to alter it with Vaadin API?

---

EDIT:
Here's popup window code as requested, but I am quite sure issue is not with this window.

```java
public class InfoNotification extends Window {
    /* Few members and constructor. Members assignment and run init() only. */

    /** This method is run from constructor */
    private void init() {
        setModal(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setStyleName("info_notification");

        okButton = new Button();
        okButton.addListener(getCloseButtonListener(this));
        okButton.setClickShortcut(ShortcutAction.KeyCode.ENTER);
        okButton.setCaption(okLabel != null ? okLabel : SessionData
            .getMessage("infoNotification.okLabel"));

        initLayout();
    }

    private void initLayout() {
        VerticalLayout componentLayout = (VerticalLayout) getContent();
        componentLayout.setWidth(600, UNITS_PIXELS);
        if (messages != null) {
            for (String message : messages) {
                componentLayout.addComponent(new Label(message));
            }
        }
        componentLayout.addComponent(okButton);
        componentLayout.setComponentAlignment(okButton,
            Alignment.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        setReadOnly(false);
    }

    public Button.ClickListener getCloseButtonListener(final Window window) {
        return new Button.ClickListener() { /* listener code */ };
    }
}
```

When I am thinking about it now, it looks like window is 600px wide, but Vaadin for some reason thinks is is very thin (couple of pixels maybe?). Result is that it reserves more height because it detects many line breaks. In fact, there is no line breaks at all, and empty space left unused. It is only my guess, though.

---

EDIT2: I found out that when I remove all size settings from component, labels get's only 87px wide. Setting different label width changes nothing.

```java
private void initLayout() {
    VerticalLayout componentLayout = (VerticalLayout) getContent();
    componentLayout.setWidth(600, UNITS_PIXELS);
    componentLayout.setSizeUndefined(); // Removes all size settings.
    // Rest of method is the same.
}
```

HTML rendered by Vaadin:

```html
<div style="height: 36px; width: 87px; overflow: hidden; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px;">
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px;">
        <div class="v-label" style="width: 87px;">a a a a a a a a a a</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show us the java code with the containers you use to add the label?
It should not behave this way (certainly not depending on the number of white spaces), there must be something else going wrong or interfering with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. Real culprit was CSS settings `.v-label { width: auto !important; }` in my *styles.css*. This one made all later width settings ignored.

Comment: This doesn't sound a proper solution. Have you tried to say label.setSizeUndefined()? The default width of label is 100%.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But then label became 87px wide, even inside wider window. Unfortunately it is project taken from another team, and we don't have time to write everything from the beginning, so we have to applied patches/fixes were possible. Main issue was, there was some unnecessary style applied. I know this is only temporary solution, but, now, at least I know issue is with CSS - there's really mess in there.